# c++ program /code to send sms to a mobile no. via internet?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sms, project, send

i want to implement sms sending module in my project .i don't have any idea how to deal with it .
if anyone know or have  C++ or Visual C++ code to send sms to a mobile no. via internet .from where i can get it or how can i implement it in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the twilio api if you want. 
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2010/12/new-c-twilio-api-wrapper-by-laurent-luce.html